# Tomcat 7 Permission Denied on deploying war file despite permissions

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Copying a war file into the `webapps` folder, it fails to deploy and I get this error in the logs:

```
Oct 09, 2020 7:09:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig beforeStart
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/myapp]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war (Permission denied)
```

I believe the `webapps` folder has the right permissions (`tomcat:tomcat /755`) as well as the `myapp.war` file (`tomcat:tomcat / 644`) yet it fails with this error.

When I unpack the war file manually (with `jar xvf myapp.war`), it works.
If I load the war file using the manager app, it works too.

I have another war file with same permissions that deploys properly, so it seems like it has to do with the war file itself, but this war file deploys properly on my local server.

So I'm really confused.

Not sure what else to check.

**EDIT:** My tomcat target user has `nologin` permission. If I manually unpack the war file as root, set ownsership to `tomcat:tomcat` to the content, and repack the war file, it then auto-deploys.

But I tried to extract the file and bring it back to local, then scp back to the tomcat server and it doesn't work anymore.

So it seems like something fishy with permissions, but not clear what it is.

Note that the source server I am sending the file from runs on Docker, as the tomcat user.

The local system I build the war file on is a Mac OSX machine. When using COPY in the Dockerfile, the files are owned by root at first, but I change onwership back to `tomcat` in the image build.

To be clear, I am building a Docker image with the war file inside. That deploys fine. Then when migrating this .war file to another VM (via scp), it doesn't deploy on the target, with the error above.

Full trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/myapp]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war (Permission denied)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:347)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:261)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:216)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1206)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1172)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:717)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:167)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:852)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Answer (score 0):

it had to do with user UID/GUID in Docker. Somehow the file was owned by the same user name but it had a different UUID in this container and it messed things up.
after insuring the same user had the same UUID in source and destination, the problem went away.